# How to use a SQL output parameter with FromSqlInterpolated? Or alternative

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

Using ASP.Net core 3.0. my Database query works - I can get the result set (records), but how to pass/get the output parameter? Also would like to know if there's a way to get the return value.

I tried using different ways to call the SQL query and the only one I was able to get working was FromSqlInterpolated, but open to different methods.

This code works for me, but I want to pass an additional parameter that can get populated as an output parameter (which is working when I test it by calling the stored proc from within SQL Server).

```
var result = _context.Users
        .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC mystoredproc  {user.Username} ").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

I tried creating a variable before the call

```
string out1 = null;
```

And then including that in the call but I can't figure out the syntax and I'm not sure if it's supported with this method.

```
var result = _context.Users
        .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC mystoredproc  {user.Username},  OUTPUT {out1}").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(out1);
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction - would like to know both how to use the output parameter and how to get the return value, not just the record set. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer accepted does not seem to work for me.
However I finally manage to have the `OUTPUT` parameter work by using the following code

```
 var p0 = new SqlParameter("@userName", {user.Username});
 var p1 = new SqlParameter("@out1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };

 string out1 = null;
 var result = _context.Users
    .FromSqlRaw($"EXEC mystoredproc  @userName, @out1 OUTPUT ", p0, p1).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

 Console.WriteLine(p1.Value); // Contains the new value of the p1 parameter
```

Just a litte warning, the p1 value property will be changed only when the request will be executed (by an `AsEnumerable`, `Load()` or anything that forces the Sql execution)

Comment: Actually, I haven't been able to get either solution to work, although they both compile and run. With Roman's solution I get nothing on the console for Console.WriteLine(out1). With nmariot's solution, if I use  Console.WriteLine(p1) then I See @out1 in the console.

Comment: Ok got it working - @nmariot your solution worked for me. But I had to use Console.WriteLine(p1.Value);

Comment: @user2026318 you're right : I've modified my code to help to understand where the return value is

Comment: the request was for FromSqlInterpolated and not FromSql as FromSql has been deprecated going forward from .net3.0

Comment: @Oduwole Oluwasegun Unfortunately, I did not find any way to use a Sql Output parameter with FromSqlInterpolated. This is why I propose a solution to definitely get the value of an output Parameter with FromSqlRaw which is quite easy to use instead of FromSqlInterpolated. Furthermore the op was also asking for an alternative ...