# getting return value from stored procedure in vs in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database context file and I created a procedure in SSMS in SQL:-

```
alter procedure gross_Sal(@empID int,@annual_sal int output)
as
begin
SELECT @annual_sal=SAL*12from EMP WHERE EMPNO=@empID
end

declare @ans int;
exec gross_Sal 1111, @annual_sal=@ans output;

select @ans as 'gross salary';
```

this works fine in SQL but I don't know how to call this in vs in c#

I have written code:-

```
   private static void paramProc()
    {
            var ctx = new trainingContext();
            var param = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName="@empno",
                    SqlDbType=System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                    Size =100,
                    Direction=System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                    Value = 1111
                },
                new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName="@annual_sal",
                    SqlDbType=System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                    Size =100,
                    Direction=System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                }
            };
            var ans = ctx.Emps.FromSqlRaw("@ans int");
            var result = ctx.Emps.FromSqlRaw("gross_Sal @empno, @annual_sal = @ans output", param[0],param[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("gross sal of the emp "+ans);
        }}
```

there might be a major mistake in my c# code but please help me with this.

I am getting this as output:-

```
     gross sal of the emp Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[HW_SQL.Models.Emp]
```

edit1:-
I tried this:-

```
var result = ctx.Emps.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC gross_Sal  @empID, @annual_sal OUTPUT", param[0], param[1]).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
 Console.WriteLine("gross salary="+param[1].Value);
```

it's going to catch block and showing error.

```
   error
```

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Your parameter names in the SP do not match the names in your code

Comment: You should use `parameterDirection.Output` in your c# code. >Check the [ParameterDirection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.parameterdirection?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Is `ctx` a DbContext of Entity Framework?

Comment: @AlexB. done and Clepus done. I tried and in console writeline and its showing error..how do I print ans?

Comment: @AlexB. yes it is

Comment: @Cleptus done but i dont know how to print the return type parameter value ..i have used ans in console writeline but thats printing error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a SQL output parameter with FromSqlInterpolated? Or alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628278/how-to-use-a-sql-output-parameter-with-fromsqlinterpolated-or-alternative)

Comment: @Cleptus i tried param[1].Value but its not printing it

Comment: You should first: 1- Remove the `var ans =...` line. 2- Change the `var result =...` line so it is similar to the linked question (do not forget the `.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()` that the answer of the question contains).

Comment: @Cleptus its going to catch block and i tried removing .AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault() then it doesnt print anything. i have edited code as you said in que

Comment: @Shadow what is Emps in `ctx.Emps.FromSqlRaw` ?

Comment: @Dave its list of object  public virtual DbSet<Emp> Emps { get; set; } here emp contains table column names

Comment: @Shadow ok, i would just try creating a new class and add it to db context as `public DbQuery<ClassName> ClassName { get; set; }` . create an `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter`  and read result into DbQuery with `await _context.ClassName.FromSql("EXEC gross_Sal  @empno = {0},objectParametervariable", empNo).ToListAsync();` . In `ClassName`, create a property with same name without space that will be returned from SP.

Comment: @Dave yeah i will try and let you know if i could find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem:-

```
 ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("gross_Sal @empID, @annual_sal OUTPUT", param);
 Console.WriteLine("gross sal of the emp "+param[1].Value);
```

I was using FromSqlRaw and I had to use EXEC to make it work like this:-

```
var result = ctx.Emps.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC gross_Sal  @empID, @annual_sal OUTPUT", param[0], param[1]).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("gross salary="+param[1].Value);
```

But that threw an error with no message. But, using

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("gross_Sal @empID, @annual_sal OUTPUT", param);
```

you can directly execute it.

I hope it helps someone who is facing the same issue.